# What is the best way in MVC to share a Layout object with between multiple HTML Helpers

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, controller

I am new to .NET MVC and am looking for a code or non-code answer to a this question.  My web application will have hundreds of controllers, partial controllers, etc.  All the controllers will share a common layout.  I am currently adding a **Menu** object to the ViewBag from the page's controller.

I'd like to know what is best practice for re-using an object multiple times in an MVC Layout view (similar to the **Menu** object in my example, below)?

```
@Html.Header(ViewBag.Menu as IR.Web.Portal.Models.Navigation.Menu)
@Html.SideNav(ViewBag.Menu as IR.Web.Portal.Models.Navigation.Menu)
@Html.Footer(ViewBag.Menu as IR.Web.Portal.Models.Navigation.Menu)
```

1. I want to initialize the object only once but use it many times.
2. I do not want to add code to every controller to make it work.  Inheritance a base controller might be a good solution.
3. The **Menu** object does not need to be in the ViewBag as it is in my example.
4. The **Menu** object will be different for every user of the site.  So, Static or Singleton classes are probably out of consideration.

Comment: Add a GloablFilter in Global.asax?  Have each Controller inherit a Base Controller?  Store object in User's Session?  Create a custom pageBaseType?  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Authentication and Logging are good fits for a Controller Base.  However, I think it is a good idea to create a Custom PageBaseType as well.  There are many things a Page should do but not a controller... Theme, Logo, Layout, Load Scripts, Possibly Get Menus, etc.

Add the following to the \Views\Web.config:

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="MyPageBase">
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

Create a class:

```
public abstract class MyPageBase<T> : WebViewPage<T>
{
    protected override void InitializePage()
    {
        ViewBag.Menu = new Menu();
        base.InitializePage();
    }
}
```